# Add same class to children element depends on ul ID

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom, getelementbyid

here is my HTML

```js
let allElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.menu_sub_box ul.lvl_1 > li");
allElements.forEach((el, index) => {
  console.log(el);
  let id = (el.id = index + 1);
});
```

```html
<div class="menu_sub_box">
      <ul class="lvl_1">
        <li>
          <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 1</a>
          <ul class="lvl_2">
            <li><a href="item1">Item 1 content</a></li>
            <li><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
            <li><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 2</a>
          <ul class="lvl_2">
            <li><a href="item1">Item 1 content</a></li>
            <li><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
            <li><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is my problem. I want to add uniqe ID to every li class ='lvl-1'. I do this by foreach loop then I want add to every children

element of  class='lvl_2' same class dependent on this ID. For example :

```html
<ul class="lvl_1">
        <li id='1'>
          <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 1</a>
          <ul class="lvl_2">
            <li class='1-col'><a href="item1">Item 1 content</a></li>
            <li class='1-col'><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
            <li class='1-col'><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id='2'>
          <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 2</a>
          <ul class="lvl_2">
            <li class='2-col'><a href="item1">Item 1 content</a></li>
            <li class='2-col'><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
            <li class='2-col'><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Sorry for my English I hope you can understand what I want to do. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this is the answer:

```js
let liElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.menu_sub_box ul.lvl_1 > li");
liElements.forEach((el, index) => {
    let id = (el.id = index + 1);
    el.id = id;
    let cols = el.querySelectorAll("li");
    cols.forEach((col) => {
        col.className = (index + 1) + "-col";
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="menu_sub_box" id="menu_sub_box">
  <ul class="lvl_1">
    <li>
      <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 1</a>
      <ul class="lvl_2">
        <li><a href="item1">Item 1 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 2</a>
      <ul class="lvl_2">
        <li><a href="item1">Item 2 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 2 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 2 content</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 3</a>
      <ul class="lvl_3">
        <li><a href="item1">Item 3 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 3 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 3 content</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For printing purpose I specified the id to the container div, in order to see the html itself after the ids were attached.Basically you can iterate through all `<li>` elements and set `id=1` then for all childs of `<ul>` append a `"-col"` to the existing id.

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll("div.menu_sub_box ul.lvl_1 > li");
lis.forEach((element, index) => {
  const id_cols = element.querySelectorAll("li");

  element.id = index + 1;

  id_cols.forEach((column) => {
    column.className = (index + 1) + "-col";
  })

})

console.log(document.getElementById("menu_sub_box").innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="menu_sub_box" id="menu_sub_box">
  <ul class="lvl_1">
    <li>
      <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 1</a>
      <ul class="lvl_2">
        <li><a href="item1">Item 1 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 1 content</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 2</a>
      <ul class="lvl_2">
        <li><a href="item1">Item 2 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 2 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 2 content</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <a class="lvl_1" href="abc">val 3</a>
      <ul class="lvl_3">
        <li><a href="item1">Item 3 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 3 content</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 3 content</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```